# Программное управление Manifest-ом

Tags: java, manifest

Так получается, что иногда мне категорически необходима в манифесте строка как `android:noHistory="true"`, а иногда категорически нужна как `android:noHistory="false"`. Могу ли я управлять этими true/false из моей программы. т.е. через код в активности?

Comment: нет, а чем `finish()` не устраивает?

Comment: Это долгая история ... но мне нужен не просто выход из программы, а ещё сброс установок .set... Я перепробовал много вариантов, и такие которые закрывают программу и её даже не видно в менеджере файлов, но выставленные установки при этом ничуть не сбрасывались и лишь с nohistory, наконец-то, происходило то, что мне нужно. Но вот беда - при выплывании окна google speech моя активность стала погибать и попытки реанимировать её в методе on result (?) (метод по окончанию голосового сканирования) не дал результата.

Comment: Действительно! finish() меня полностью устроил. Спасибо, это уже вторая подсказка от вас. А я раньше считал, что бармалей это плохой. Плохой бармалей это стереотип навязанный обществом).

Answer (score 2):

При запуске `activity` добавляете в `intent` соответствующий флаг

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
```